# ionic reCaptacha not showing up

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, recaptcha

Following the instructions from Google, I added the approproate scripts in my index.html file :

```
Paste this snippet before the closing </head> tag on your HTML template:
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
Paste this snippet at the end of the <form> where you want the reCAPTCHA widget to appear:
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="MY_KEY"></div>
The reCAPTCHA documentation site describes more details and advanced configurations.
```

There is no capatcha though. It is just blank. Is installing reCaptcha the same as it would be with a website? Are there any steps how to add reCaptacha into Ionic as I couldn't not find anything?

Comment: why use recaptcha in mobile application?

Comment: to prevent bots from registering. Very easy to retrieve my .apk file, run locally on a computer, and have script bots start registering. As a result, I want to make sure reCapatcha is included to prevent spam bots from registering.

Comment: I think you have use sms verification or email verification is better then recaptcha.

Comment: <html>
  <head>
    <title>reCAPTCHA demo: Explicit render after an onload callback</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var onloadCallback = function() {
        grecaptcha.render('html_element', {
          'sitekey' : 'your_site_key'
        });
      };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="?" method="POST">
      <div id="html_element"></div>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit"
        async defer>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>